# In SQL is it faster to use subqueries or to build the subqueries into tables and then query from those?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm doing work involving a lot of joining between tables, and I've been taught that using subqueries is a lot slower than other commands, but in some of the stuff I have been doing it seems necessary to either use a subquery or create a new table. Because I might be calling the same subquery multiple times, I've been building analogous tables for each subquery instead and using those. Does this seem efficient? Please let me know if I should be doing things a different way.

Comment: Your question is essentially thus: So is it faster to do the extra work every time so its done when you need it? Or to just do it when you need it. And the answer is it depends on how you use it! In short, at least.

Comment: Thought experiment: Which of those options sounds like it would cause the DB to do more work?

Comment: *I've been taught that using subqueries is a lot slower than other commands* As a general principle, this is useless. With SQL, the devil is in the details. Many factors come together like the musicians in an orchestra to create the final sound.

Comment: Execution plans are your friend.  Run your queries both ways, and see which one performs worse.

Comment: Search this site, you will find a lot of examples where the results have varied.  It really depends on the query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Making a blanket statement that using subqueries is a lot slower than other commands is just plain wrong. As usual, it depends. No one here is going to be able to give you a definitive answer to your question. But, this should be easy to figure out yourself. You can easily create both approaches, and examine the generated query plans in SSMS and the query statistics in Profiler (something you should be doing anyway). This will determine the best approach for your particular problem.

Comment: "Include Actual Execution Plan" is grayed out in the query dropdown, does this mean I don't have permission? My company also doesn't let me use sqlcmd so this wouldn't surprise me. I'm also having trouble finding the profiler

Comment: Do you have access to "Display Estimated Execution Plan". Profiler should be in your Microsoft SQL Server 2008 | Performance Tools folder, unless your company doesn't let you use that either.

Comment: No I don't have access to that. I've tried looking for the performance tools folder but haven't found it

Answer (score 0):

You aren't limited to just these 2 choices. You could use a subquery, CTE, temp table, or table variable in your query. You could maintain a view, indexed view, or table outside of your query. Which one will perform the best depends on what your query is doing exactly, how many rows are in the target tables, existing indexes, how much disk space/RAM is available on the machine, etc. Also, if you are using a subquery, is there maybe a way to write your entire query so that the subquery isn't called multiple times? Maybe using some creative way of joining or something to put it into a set-based operation?

Answer (score 0):

There is no right or wrong answer, but the likeliest correct answer is to use a Common Table Expression or CTE.

The main thing you need to bear in mind is that performance varies wildly depending on a bunch of factors including the amount of data, the spread or statistics of the data, indexes, how selective or general your sub-queries are, how fast your disks are, how much of the query can be kept in memory and a whole bunch of other stuff.

Generally speaking, write both queries and add the following before the first query:

```
SET STATISTICS IO ON
```

Then run the batch and switch views to 'messages' rather than viewing the datasets - you will see the 'logical reads' incurred (amongst other stuff) for each query and each table.

Generally speaking, you want those logical reads to be lower.

Make sure you run this test with a copy of live data if possible since that will give you the closest approximation to what will happen when this runs on the live server. (closest approximation again because the SQL optimiser may be optimising for general server load due to e.g. replication or user activity or other reports running or anything really)

Going by the description you make of calling the same subquery multiple times, it sounds like CTEs are what you are looking for and these frequently perform better than alternatives.